# A simple stats calculator for Koloboks

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting this to prompt the user to copy a code to then reveal the stats. I've gotten it to work with just making var e the sequence in question but that requires copy and pasting it into a console. I'm wanting to turn it into a simple calculator essentially but I have no real experience in coding start to finish on any kind of programing language. My end goal though is to try to turn it into a userscript applet. I only post here as I know there are people here with a lot of skills and could likely do this in their sleep. I am currently going back and looking at old userscripts I used to use for games and such(kingdoms of camelot made it so that you needed userscripts to play it.) Just in the hopes of finding the coding I would need to use and modifying it for doing this down here.

```
var e = Prompt("Copy and Paste The Genome Sequence here.");
const t = e.length;
const n = e.length / 2;
const l = [e.slice(0, 2), e.slice(t - 2, t)];
const r = [e.slice(n - 2, n), e.slice(n, n + 2)];

var speed = Math.abs(parseInt(l[0], 16) - parseInt(l[1], 16));
var stealth = ((255 - Math.abs(parseInt(r[0], 16) - parseInt(r[1], 16))) / 255).toFixed(2);

console.log(stealth)
console.log(speed)
```

I hope I can find some help, I'm not necessarily wanting someone to do it for me or anything like that I am trying to learn by doing this. But any help is appreciated!
This is the html that I want the applet to natively grab when connected to the right webpage concerning the Kolobok itself.

```
<span _ngcontent-embryo-seo-pre-c42="" class="ng-star-inserted">07a952a4c44d38ade1189319e1b418add8f7325959d5ff65bc2539b0943bd4fd</span>
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us what your code should be doing. What exactly is wrong with your code? What is an example of the intended input and output?